# CMake qt input library postfix for custom debug build

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I'm stuck with writing a cmake file for multiconfiguration IDE (Visual Studio).
My goal is to add a custom configuration and tell Visual Studio that I want to use debug libs of Qt (qtcored.lib) as it is done when I pick Debug configuration. With code below, I have release libraries in a linker input when I  pick CustomDebug configuration

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Thanks

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12.0)

project(custom-conf)

find_package(Qt5Core        CONFIG REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set(SRC main.cpp)

set(QT_LIBS Qt5::Core)

add_executable(custom-conf WIN32 ${SRC})

target_link_libraries(custom-conf ${QT_LIBS})

#
get_property(isMultiConfig GLOBAL PROPERTY GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG)

if(isMultiConfig)
    set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "CustomDebug;Debug;Release" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_CUSTOMDEBUG "/debug")
endif()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to use debug libs of Qt (qtcored.lib) as it is done when I pick Debug configuration.

With the IMPORTED target this can be easiliy achieved by using [MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG<CONFIG>](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_CONFIG.html) **target property**:

```
# For CustomDebug configuration of the main project
# use Debug configuration of the IMPORTED target
set_target_properties(Qt5::Core PROPERTIES
    MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_CUSTOMDEBUG DEBUG)
```

With setting [CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG<CONFIG>](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_CONFIG.html) **variable** you may automatically set the property for all IMPORTED targets:

```
set(CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_CUSTOMDEBUG DEBUG)
#...
# This call will create IMPORTED target Qt5::Core which
# MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_CUSTOMDEBUG property is already set.
find_package(Qt5Core CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

(The variable assignment should come **before** any call like `find_package` which creates IMPORTED target.)

Comment: Digging in qt cmake files I found out that internal it uses only    _populate_Core_target_properties(DEBUG "Qt5Cored.dll" "Qt5Cored.lib" ) and I had to map these properties. Thanks for answer